# How to change baseQuery redux when language changing with i18n?

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-redux, rtk-query

I need to change `baseQuery` when `AsyncSorage` variable changing or i18n language changing (this the same thing).

This code works, but it doesn't change dynamically. I need to reload app and language are change

I tried `apiSlice.updateBaseQuery` but it didn't help to me

Here is the code.

```
import {createApi,fetchBaseQuery} from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';
import React, {useState,useEffect, useCallback} from 'react';
import useGetLanguage from '../Hooks/useGetLanguage'
import i18n from 'i18next';
import { fetchData } from './fetchData';

const customBaseQuery = async (url, options) => {
    const language = await AsyncStorage.getItem('Language') == 1 ? 'en' : 'ru'
    const baseUrl = `http://oralbekov.dias19.fvds.ru/${language}`;
    return fetchBaseQuery({ baseUrl })(url, options);
  };

export const apiSlice = createApi({
    baseQuery:customBaseQuery,
    tagTypes: [
        'PopularQuestions',
        'CategoryQuestion',
        'QuestionsCategory',
        'CategoryTheory',
        'CategoryTheoryArticle',
        'Articles',
        'ArticleById',
        'HajjDays',
        'HajjStartDate',
        'UmrahDays',
        'Translate',
        'CategoryQuestions',
      ],
      
    endpoints: (builder) => ({
        getQuestionCategory: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/questions/categories/',
            providesTags: ['QuestionsCategory']
        }),
        getPopularQuestions: builder.query({
            query: () => 'api/questions/popular',
            providesTags: ['PopularQuestions']
        }),
        getCategoryQuestions: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/questions/category/${id}`,
            providesTags: ['CategoryQuestions']
        }),
        getCategoryTheoryMain: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/info/main`,
            providesTags: ['CategoryTheory']
        }),
        getCategoryTheoryArticle: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/info/${id}`,
            providesTags: ['CategoryTheoryArticle']
        }),
        getArticles: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/news/`,
            providesTags: ['Articles']
        }),
        getArticleById: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/news/${id}`,
            providesTags: ['ArticleById']
        }),
        getHajjStartDate: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/calendar/get_hajj_date`,
            providesTags: ['HajjStartDate']
        }),
        getHajjDays: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/calendar/hajj`,
            providesTags: ['HajjDays']
        }),
        getUmrahDays: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/calendar/umrah`,
            providesTags: ['UmrahDays']
        }),
        getTranslate: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/translate`,
            providesTags: ['Translate']
        }),
        getTranslateById: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/translate/categories/${id}`
        }),
        getPlaces: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/maps/places`
        }),
        getRestaurants: builder.query({
            query: () => `api/maps/restaurants`
        }),
        getRestaurantById: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/maps/restaurants/${id}`
        }),
        getPlaceById: builder.query({
            query: (id) => `api/maps/places/${id}`
        }),
    })
})`

export const { 
    useGetQuestionCategoryQuery,
    useGetCategoryQuestionsQuery, 
    useGetPopularQuestionsQuery, 
    useGetCategoryTheoryMainQuery, 
    useGetArticlesQuery,
    useGetArticleByIdQuery, 
    useGetCategoryTheoryArticleQuery,
    useGetHajjStartDateQuery, useGetHajjDaysQuery, useGetUmrahDaysQuery,useGetTranslateQuery,useGetTranslateByIdQuery,
    useGetPlacesQuery,useGetPlaceByIdQuery,useGetRestaurantsQuery,useGetRestaurantByIdQuery} = apiSlice
```